# Expected Value of a function of the standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, expectation

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a good start.  Now, notice that
$$
(z-a)^{+}=\begin{cases}z-a & \text{if }z\geq a\\0 & \text{else}\end{cases},
$$
so that
$$
\mathbb{E}[(Z-a)^+]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(z-a)^{+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\,dz=\int_{-\infty}^{a}0\,dz+\int_a^{\infty}(z-a)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\,dz.
$$
The first integral just evaluates to $0$, and disappears; what should you do with the rest?

Try breaking it up over subtraction, and see if you can figure out where each part of the given formula is coming from.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot that I could split the integral up since the function is piecewise. I did the integral and got the right answer. :). Thanks again that made so much sense